# How to remove duplicate integers in my code?

Tags: java, loops

user input a number  ,if i repeat same the number and write the number in my text file. how can i stop the duplication. ?

i create a text file and write numbers in my text file.. if i write same number repeatedly that was write in my file..please correct my code.. i want write a number only one time....

```
public class FileOp extends Thread {
    volatile String s = "yes";

    void create() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String filename = "Numberfile.txt";

        File file = new File(filename);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        if (file.createNewFile()) {

            System.out.println("\nFile '" + filename + "' has
                    been created.\n");

        } else {

            System.out.println("\nFile '" + filename + "'
                    already exists.\n");
        }


    }

    void write() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Numberfile.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


        do {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a number :");

            int a = in.nextInt();

            bw.write("" + a + "\n");

            System.out.println("Succesfully added in
                    Numberfile");


            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            System.out.println("Do you want continue
            (yes / no) ? ");

            s = in.next();


        }
        while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

i enter a number `2` and it write in my text file,and i enter the number `2` repeatedly .. its store in text file. i don't want that..  only one time it's write in text file,

Comment: How big and how small numbers can be? Is it full integer, or just > 0 && < 10000 ?

Comment: You need some way to track which numbers were previously entered. Probably some `List`. Then you check if it contains that number or not.

Comment: Consider using `Set`.

Comment: You can use a array to check if the number is already in the textfile. And at the start of the program you load every number into your array. You can then easily check if its already in the file

Comment: Use [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: yes...  and also it's integer

Comment: please correct my code???

Comment: how can i add 'set'??? in my code? i don't know were its add?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need set, just make a list of type Integer that contains the previous numbers added. Use list.add(number) to add and list.contains(number) to check if number already exists in the list before writing to file/adding to list.
declaring a list of type integer:  `List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();`

Also go check out the Collections in java: 
[Class Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Collections.html)

edit: set declaration: `Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: You can do the same with `Set`. It is even better because `contains` is O(1) (usually with good hashing function and without hash collisions). And `contains` for `list` is O(n).

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Thank you.